# Why is this null check incurring a null dereference error?

Tags: c#, .net

So basically I want to check that a setting is not set in my C# application. The code here

```
if (Default["StudentAccountTypeDefault"] is null) // Crashes after this
{
    //
}
else
{
    //
}
```

seems to be crashing on the null-check. I've put a breakpoint there, and it shows `Default["DefaultStudentAccountType"]` to just be a blank string. Why is it crashing with a NullReferenceException? I'm pretty sure this is where it crashes-if I comment out if statement it works as expected.

Edit: To alleviate some confusion. Sooooo, `Default` is actually `Settings.Default`, and to add to that, I was actually trying to access it inside the Settings() constructor. So, before it had been initialized, obviously. Oops. "Full"-er code below.

```
public Settings() {
    // // To add event handlers for saving and changing settings, uncomment the lines below:
    //
    // this.SettingChanging += this.SettingChangingEventHandler;
    //
    // this.SettingsSaving += this.SettingsSavingEventHandler;
    //
    if (Settings.Default["DefaultStudentAccountType"] is null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Its `Settings.Default`. I was trying to access it inside the constructor, which is a silly idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should be checking with `==` not with `is`, also depending on your data type you may need to check if `Default` is null too. Try this:

```
if(Default == null || Default["StudentAccountTypeDefault"] == null)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: `Default` is really `Settings.Default`. It still crashes when I do that though--Oh, I figured it out. Going to edit main post.

Comment: Or `Default?["StudentAccountTypeDefault"] == null` for later versions of C#

Comment: @phuzi: That is true, although I think I would prefer the readability of my answer, but that is just my opinion of course

Answer (score 1):

`Default` is a variable, so if it is null, accessing the indexer `["StudentAccountTypeDefault"]` will throw a null reference exception.

If you're using a new enough .NET version, you can use:

`if (Default?["StudentAccountTypeDefault"] is null)`

(the null-coalescing operator). Otherwise, just check `Default` for null before using its indexer.